# I want to block permission(Manifest.permission.READ_LOGS) in My Application

Tags: android

I want to block permission(Manifest.permission.READ_LOGS) in My Application.
some application used to saw LogCat in android phone.some error are saw by user.
how block this

Comment: can you further explain it a little ? Are you trying to develop an application or do you want to deny permision to an application installed in your phone?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot block permission from another application. If your concern is what gets placed in the logs... don't place anything in the logs.